# How to create Increment and Decrement routes in Mongoose and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I have an inventory collection with quantity fields, I would like to create two endpoints, one that increments the value of the quantity field (by _id), while the other route should Decrement it.

//Schema

```
   name : {type:String},
   description : {type:String},
   price : {type:Number},
   quantity :{ type: Number,default:0},
   supplier : {type:String},
   taxable :{type:Boolean},

},{timestamps:true});

module.exports=Inventory=mongoose.model('item',ItemSchema,'inventory');
```

Increment route

```
router.post('/counter/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id;
Inventory.findOneAndUpdate({_id :id}, {$inc : {'quantity' : 1}}).exec((err, results) => 
{ if (err) throw err; res.json(results); })
});
```

Decrement route

```
router.post('/counter/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id;
Inventory.findOneAndUpdate({_id :id}, {$inc : {'quantity' : -1}}).exec((err, results) => 
{ if (err) throw err; res.json(results); })
});
```

When I test the route using Postman, I get a 200K response, but nothing happens to the quantity fields value it neither increment nor decrement

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use following code for increment and Decrement quantity
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

Increment : 
Inventory.findOneAndUpdate({_id :mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, { $inc: { quantity : 1 }},{ new: true }).then((results) => { console.log(results)});

Decrement : 
Inventory.findOneAndUpdate({_id :mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, { $inc: { quantity : -1 }},{ new: true }).then((results) => { console.log(results)});
```

Comment: Still getting a 200K response, No change in the quantity field value

Comment: Inventory.update({_id :mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, { $inc: { 'quantity' : -1 }}).then((results) => { console.log(results)});
 Please use that code